# Não consigo atualizar um projeto Ruby no Heroku com o Git

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

Ao tentar dar commit em umas alteração que fiz no meu projeto Ruby e subir para o Heroku, tive uma mensagem de erro.

Dentro da pasta do projeto no terminal executei os comandos:

```
$ git status
$ git add .
$ git commit -m 'msg'
$ git push heroku master
```

O seguinte erro foi retornado:

> ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first) error: failed to
>   push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/still-coast-1656.git' dica:
>   Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
>   dica: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository
>   pushing dica: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the
>   remote changes dica: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
>   dica: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for
>   details.

Tentei iniciar um novo repositório para enviar novamente;

```
$ git init
$ git add .
$ git commit -m 'msg'
```

Novo erro foi informado:

> No ramo master nada a submeter, diretório de trabalho vazio

Como faço para subir/atualizar meu projeto no heroku?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O primeiro erro indica que seu projeto está desatualizado em relação ao que está no heroku. Você tem duas opções. A primeira é:

```
git pull --rebase heroku master
```

E nesse caso você resolve o rebase para alinhar as branchs. Uma vez isso feito, você consegue fazer o push normalmente.

A segunda opção é a mais fácil:

```
git push -f heroku master
```

O `-f` significa force. Nesse caso você está dizendo "Heroku, a branch é minha, faz o que estou mandando e pronto". Ele simplesmente vai ignorar qualquer conflito, e vai adotar a sua branch como a mais atual.